# Caption is created with value but pic(media) is empty in strapi. i've used graphql also but failed to upload image to a certain collection type

Tags: reactjs, axios, strapi

I've used graphql at first and with maximum possible ways in Altair.
Then I shifted to axios, but dosen't able to upload the image.
Here is my actual component

if i use api/upload with ref, refId, field that uploads to media library. But i want to create new collection entry for certain collection type

I didn't able to find that where the problem is. So, there is no remaining ways to try. What can I do now?

```
//no problem with imports
const CreateFrontimage = () => {
    const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  
    const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
        console.log(formData);
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/api/gallery-images', formData);
  
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Frontimage created successfully.');
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to create frontimage entry.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating frontimage entry:', error);
      }
    };
  
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
        <Controller
            name="files.pic"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.files[0])}
                />
            )}
            />
  
        <label htmlFor="caption">Caption:</label>
        <Controller
            name="data.caption"
            control={control}
            defaultValue="" // Set an initial value for the caption
            render={({ field }) => (
                <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Caption"
                value={field.value}
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)}
                />
            )}
            />
  
        <button type="submit">Create Frontimage</button>
      </form>
    );
  };
```

caption updated but pic's are not:

[image]

the console.log of (formData)

[image]

I've tried to upload image/media with axios and graphql to strapi collection but failed
also tried with older version of axios ["axios": "^0.21.4"]